# NLog custom LayoutRenderer for scope indentation

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

can any one provide me of a very sample custom layoutrenderer for nlog ?

I want to make indentation while im logging , by example

if im calling Method B from Method C

the Text log file goes like this :

```
Inside Method C
       Inside Method B
```

and so on.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74162667/193178

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here it is:

```
[LayoutRenderer("IndentationLayout")]
public sealed class IndentationLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    // Value to substract from stack count
    private uint _ignore = 12;

    // Value to pad with.
    private string _ipadding = "| ";

    /// <summary>Set the number of (top) stackframes to ignore</summary>
    public uint Ignore
    {
        get { return _ignore; }
        set { _ignore = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>Set the padding value</summary>
    public string IndentationPadding
    {
        get { return _ipadding; }
        set { _ipadding = value; }
    }

    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo ev)
    {
        // Get current stack depth, insert padding chars.
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
        long indent = st.FrameCount;
        indent = indent > _ignore ? indent - _ignore : 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < indent; ++i)
        {
            builder.Append(_ipadding);
        }
    }
}
```

Registration:

```
if(NLog.Config.ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.LayoutRenderers.AllRegisteredItems.ContainsKey(
                "IndentationLayout"))
                return;

NLog.Config.ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.LayoutRenderers.RegisterDefinition("IndentationLayout", typeof(IndentationLayoutRenderer));
```

Comment: Do you know if I can configure the LayoutRenderers in nlog.config file?

Comment: `StackTrace might not report as many method calls as expected, due to code transformations that occur during optimization.` - [MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx)  I would consider creating static Indent, UnIndent methods which take a Logger as well as having a `private static Dictionary<Logger.LoggerName, IndentLevel>`.  Then in the Append, check the dictionary using LogEventInfo.LoggerName to get your IndentLevel.

Comment: You could configure this in nlog.config like this: `${IndentationLayout}{message}`

Comment: Please note there is a huge performance penalty by using this LayoutRenderer (Because of StackTrace-capture)

Answer (score 0):

With NLog 5.0.5 then you can use [${scopeindent}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ScopeIndent-Layout-Renderer)

```
${scopeindent}${message}
```

```cs
Logger.Info("Hello No Scope");              // Will not be indented

using (NLog.ScopeContext.PushNestedState("First Scope"))
{
   Logger.Info("Hello First Scope");        // Will be indented once
   await InnerOperationAsync();
}

static async Task InnerOperationAsync()
{
    using (NLog.ScopeContext.PushNestedState("Second Scope"))
    {
        Logger.Info("Hello Second Scope");   // Will be indented twice
        await Task.Yield();
    }
}
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74162667/193178