# Custom NLog LayoutRenderer with constructor using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog

I am trying to write a custom LayoutRenderer that logs data read from an object, but it seems that NLog is not working properly with Dependency Injection.

Here is my CustomLayoutRenderer:

```
[LayoutRenderer("custom-value")]
public class CustomLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    private readonly RequestContext _context;

    public CustomLayoutRenderer(RequestContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        builder.Append(_context.CustomValue);
    }
}
```

It is using this RequestContext object:

```
public class RequestContext
{
    public string CustomValue { get; set; } = "Valid custom value";
}
```

I am also wiring up DI, configuring NLog and registering my LayoutRenderer in Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
        services.AddScoped<RequestContext>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        LayoutRenderer.Register<CustomLayoutRenderer>("custom-value");

        loggerFactory.AddNLog();
        app.AddNLogWeb();
        env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
        // ...
    }
```

I am then trying to use my `${custom-value}` in nlog.config, but I am getting an error on the `AddNLog()` call:

> 2017-02-03 13:08:08.0284 Error Parsing configuration from [project-folder]\bin\Debug\net452\win7-x64\NLog.config failed.
>   Exception:     NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Exception when parsing [project-folder]\bin\Debug\net452\win7-x64\NLog.config.
>   NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Cannot access the constructor of type: ATest.CustomLayoutRenderer. Is the required permission granted?
>   at NLog.Internal.FactoryHelper.CreateInstance(Type t)
>   ...

### Notes

The reason why I am trying this is that I would like to log some information accessible only from the controller (like the TraceIdentifier, parts of the URL, and some request-specific custom stuff). The values in RequestContext would be set by the controller when it gets a request.

The following Renderer works as expected, which makes me think this is a dependency injection problem:

```
[LayoutRenderer("custom-value")]
public class CustomLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        builder.Append("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

I did see this [NLog bug](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/issues/34) but it's marked as fixed now, which is why I am posting here rather than there.

And for the sake of completeness, here is what I have added to my `project.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "NLog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-*",
    "NLog.Web.AspNetCore": "4.3.0"
},
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two methodes:

#### 1) DI aware

You could make NLog DI aware. Add to your startup.cs:

```cs
ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.CreateInstance = (Type type) =>
{ 
    // your custom target. Could be a better check ;)
    if(type == typeof(CustomLayoutRenderer))
      return new CustomLayoutRenderer(...); // TODO get RequestContext
    else
      return Activator.CreateInstance(type); //default
};
```

This is a more generic approach.

#### 2) AspNetMvcLayoutRendererBase

Or, override from `AspNetMvcLayoutRendererBase` (NLog.Web.AspNetCore) and use `HttpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.TryGetRequest()` and don't add the constructor.

This only works when needing `HttpContext`.

```cs
[LayoutRenderer("custom-value")]
public class MyCustomRenderer : AspNetLayoutRendererBase
{
    protected override void DoAppend(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        var httpRequest = HttpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.TryGetRequest();

        if (httpRequest == null)
            return;


        builder.Append(httpRequest.Something); //TODO

    }
}
```

Comment: The second method doesn't seem to work?  TryGetRequest() doesn't seem to live on that class, and the HttpContextAccessor always seems to be null in this.

Comment: @julian Would be great to have a generic solution that works with Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection or similar.

Comment: I think you could combine the `CreateInstance` with Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the NLog source code for `FactoryHelper`. It looks like you have to provide a default constructor.

You may want to also consider using the layout renders from NLog.Web package. There are several that can get request-specific information. There even an option to log stuff from `HttpContext` with `${aspnet-Item}` layout

If that doesn't suit you perhaps a "stateful" logger will work like the one in the answer I gave here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32857908/1289052

Comment: That question is so messy.. I like your answer, but I'd like to leverage ASP.NET Core's built-in DI system, so I don't have to write my `Set`s in every single class. I saw that I can probably use `${aspnet-Request-Url}` for the parts of the URL that I need, but that's kind of my last resort solution. I would like to set this, the TraceIdentifier, and my custom variables in the same way since I can access all of them from my controller.