# NLog: indent messages

Tags: c#, nlog

Example: method A calls method B, B calls C, all methods write messages to log. Is it possible to automatically indent messages with NLog like so?

```
String in method A before B is called
    First string in method B
    Second string in method B and call C
        First string in method C
        Second string in method C
    Third string in method B after C is called
String in method A after B is called
```

Maybe there is some API to specify current indent level, so all subsequent outputting to log will use this level?

Comment: Seems a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951102/nlog-custom-layoutrenderer

Comment: This blog post also uses a custom layoutrenderer : http://nlog-forum.1685105.n2.nabble.com/Intentation-td1685697.html

Comment: Yes, thank you, seems like duplicate..